# How does Mercurial merge internally?

Tags: mercurial, branching-and-merging

There is a nifty article on quora about how git does it's merging:
http://www.quora.com/Git-revision-control/How-does-git-merge-work

And I was wondering if such a thing existed for Mercurial.

I'll admit that my motivation for this is that Mercurial seems really dumb about auto-resolving conflicts, but without concrete information about how mercurial does it's merging, I can't form an argument for Git. (Also maybe I'm crazy and the method is the same, regardless I can't find the information about how HG merges, anywhere.)

Also I hear HG is super configurable, so if there is a tool to make the merging less dumb, I would love to hear about it.

As an example of the silliness HG appeared to do, it gave a number of conflicts with other empty, such as:

```
<<<<<<<< local
[some new code...]
========
>>>>>>>> other
```

EDIT: So, I'm also looking for a merge tool that can intelligently auto-resolve conflicts. Like, it should be able to resolve the above example, which is painfully simple to resolve.

Comment: Not sure how HG does it but the link about Git merging is excellent. Thanks.

Comment: Mercurial is **not** dumb in auto-merge, at least it merges with the same quality as Git. I hope, @mpm can answer better and deeply

Comment: Ah, I chatted to mpm a couple days ago on the Mercurial irc, I think. Cool guy.
I'm going to add an example as to why I think it appears to be of a different quality.

Comment: I just did another merge and it didn't mark conflicts in spots where there were definitely conflicts. I had regressions in my code because of it. I feel like the method they used was to randomly choose which side to choose when a real conflict occurs, then when there there is simply new code, mark it as a conflict.

Comment: Because of someone screwing up the access of a branch making me unable to commit a day of work and a coworker overwriting a previous push, I was fired from my job today. I never thought a source control tool would get me unemployed >.>;;

Answer (score 1):

Mercurial largely leaves merging to an external programs. See

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration

and

https://www.mercurial-scm.org/repo/hg/help/merge-tools

From the last page:

> Mercurial uses these rules when deciding which merge tool to use:
>
> 1. If a tool has been specified with the --tool option to merge or
>    resolve, it is used.  If it is the name of a tool in the merge-tools
>    configuration, its configuration is used. Otherwise the specified tool
>    must be executable by the shell.
> 2. If the "HGMERGE" environment variable
>    is present, its value is used and must be executable by the shell.
> 3. If the filename of the file to be merged matches any of the patterns in
>    the merge-patterns configuration section, the first usable merge tool
>    corresponding to a matching pattern is used. Here, binary capabilities
>    of the merge tool are not considered.
> 4. If ui.merge is set it will be
>    considered next. If the value is not the name of a configured tool,
>    the specified value is used and must be executable by the shell.
>    Otherwise the named tool is used if it is usable.
> 5. If any usable merge tools are present in the merge-tools configuration
>    section, the one with the highest priority is used.
> 6. If a program named "hgmerge" can be
>    found on the system, it is used - but it will by default not be used
>    for symlinks and binary files.
> 7. If the file to be merged is not binary and is not a symlink, then
>    "internal:merge" is used.
>
> 8.The merge of the file fails and must be resolved before commit.
>
> Note: After selecting a merge program, Mercurial will by default attempt to
> merge the files using a simple merge algorithm first. Only if it doesn't
> succeed because of conflicting changes Mercurial will actually execute the
> merge program. Whether to use the simple merge algorithm first can be
> controlled by the premerge setting of the merge tool. Premerge is
> enabled by default unless the file is binary or a symlink.

Comment: This is a great first step. Now what is the decision flow that HG's premerge algorithm uses? And does internal:merge do anything besides marking the differences between the files?