# Programmatically pre-merge in mercurial (or git)

Tags: git, merge, mercurial

There are certain common, uninformative merge conflicts we experience regularly, particularly when merging regression test outputs.  I'd like to be able to programmatically ignore lines matching certain patterns (e.g., "if a line or region matches this regexp, just take the patch from *other*"), but then I still want to hand off to an interactive merge tool to handle *other* conflicts in the file if there are any (without having to manually re-merge those first lines.)

If I pre-merge with any tool (like `:merge3` or any I might devise) and then re-merge with another tool, it seems to always start from scratch.  Is there any way to "save my work" for the conflicts I've already resolved?

We use `mercurial`, but if the process is similar in `git`, please let me know.

Answer (score 3):

The process *is* different in Git, but you should be able to achieve what you want in either system.

The TL;DR is that you must write your own merge tool (or merge driver, in Git).  This merge tool should compare the three input files and do whatever merging you want, then run the normal low level merge driver with a new set of base and input files.

#### Long

First, note that Mercurial has its own definition of "premerge".  See https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration for a more complete description.  I'm interpreting your question as not involving this kind of pre-merge at all; instead, you want to write what Mercurial refers to as a *merge tool*.  (Git calls this a *merge driver*.)

Let's have with a few definitions so that we all agree on terminology.  When you run `hg merge` or `git merge`, you select two particular commits to merge.  One is your current commit, which we'll call *local* since Mercurial uses that name.  We will call the other commit *other* for the same reason.  (Mercurial sometimes calls the second one *remote*, but mostly internally-only.  Git variably calls these `--ours` and `--theirs`, or *local* and *remote*, or *local* and *other*: Git is not at all good about being consistent.)

You check out the local commit and run `hg merge other` or `git merge other`, and Mercurial or Git will find the *merge base* commit, which they both call the merge base or just the base.

In both systems, all three interesting commits are represented as snapshots:  Here are the files as of the base commit.  Here are the same (and maybe some new, some deleted, some renamed) files as of the local commit.  Here are the same files as of the other commit.  *Hey, Mr <strike>Tambourine Man</strike> Version System, make a merge for me.*

#### High level merges

The first thing the VCS must do is pair-up each base-commit file with each local-commit file and each other-commit file.  There might be two of these actions on a file-as-a-whole (create, rename, or delete).  In particular, if a file has been renamed in one or both commits, the VCS must deal with this.  If the file was deleted in one or both commits, the VCS must deal with that.  If a file that did not exist in the base was created in both commits, the VCS must deal with that, too.  Some of these are straightforward: if file *F* was renamed in just *one* of the two commits, well, we just rename it in the final result, while otherwise combining changes as usual.  But other changes conflict with each other: which name should the VCS use, if both commits renamed the file?  I call these clashes *high level* conflicts.<sup>1</sup>

Here, Git has an advantage of sorts over Mercurial.  Mercurial makes you choose a resolution for each high level conflict right away, so that it knows the ultimate fate of each file.<sup>2</sup>  Git makes you defer this decision (though there's a problem with the underlying implementation, in Git).  I'll mention a bit more about this in a moment.  This part, you cannot automate very well in Mercurial (or at least could not the last time I tried).  Fortunately for both VCSes, these kinds of conflicts tend to be rare.

#### Low level merges

Now that we know the fate of all the files (or have deferred this decision in Git), Mercurial in particular will use the tool you choose (via `--tool` or `$HGMERGE`) to merge each file.  I call this a *low level* merge, to distinguish it from the high level process of pairing up files and determining their names.  This low level merge process is outlined in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21649886/1256452) to [How does Mercurial merge internally?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21637143/1256452)

Remember, we have three inputs: base, local, and other.  The final merge will have *two* parents: local and other.  We can think about each low level file as being "changed" in either parent, when compared to the base.  Or, the file could be the same as it is in either or both parents.  If the file has not been touched at all—if it's exactly the same in all three commits—there's nothing to do: the final file should match the base file.  If the file has been modified in just *one* parent—in local or in other, with respect to what's in the base—then there's *still* nothing to do, really; we can just use the modified one.

If the file has been changed in *exactly the same way* in both parents, it's not going to matter which parent we use.  But note that [this wiki page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergeToolConfiguration) says that this process applies:

> For each file changed in both parents ...

Here, there's some subtlety and it's worth looking at another difference between Git and Mercurial.

In Git, when we have our three files from B (base), L (local), and O (other), what we really have are three *hash IDs*.  Hash IDs uniquely identify content, so we can immediately tell which files match and which don't.  If L = O, both parents have the same version of the file and we just take one of those, regardless of B (either both made the same change, or no one made any change).  Otherwise, if B = L or B = O, we take the one that it *doesn't* match, because that's the parent with the change.  Otherwise (B ≠ L, B ≠ O, L ≠ O) we must do a real merge.

Mercurial doesn't store files by hash ID.  Instead, it knows if a file was changed somewhere along the commits leading from B to L, and somewhere along the commits leading from B to O.  So it just looks to see if both parents' commit sequences modified the file since B.

**The upshot of all this is that in Git, your merge driver will run only if all three inputs differ.  In Mercurial, your merge tool can run if both parents touched the file, but two or even all three of the inputs might match.**  In most cases this makes no difference, but keep it in mind for special corner cases.  Mercurial's built in pre-merge (the one you're not talking about) handles this particular case for you, so unless you disable the pre-merge, you won't actually *see* it.

When your merge driver gets run, you pass to it the names of the three inputs and the output file, as in the example from my first link to the Mercurial wiki:

```
mymergetool.args = $local $other $base -o $output
```

(this comes from your `.hgrc` or equivalent).  In Git, it's similar, except that you define a *merge driver* in your `.gitconfig` or similar:

```
driver = filfre %O %A %B
```

and then refer to this driver from a `.gitattributes` file, and one of the three input files is also the output file (see [the gitattributes documentation](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/gitattributes.html#_defining_a_custom_merge_driver) for details).

Your merge tool / merge driver must read the three input files and use that to compute and write the correct output file—*in one step* as seen by the version control system.  You can use as many steps *internally* as you like.  When you are done, you should exit with a status of 0 if the output file is the correct result of the full merge, or nonzero (generally just 1) if the merge needs hand-editing or further work.

In your case, you will analyze the differences, combine some changes yourself, create three *new* input files, and run some other file merge tool on the file.  Mercurial doesn't seem to have a good way to run its own internal low level file merger; [this wiki page](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/MergingManuallyInEditor) suggests instead using GNU `diff3` to do the job, and includes a script to run `diff3` and if it indicates conflicts, run `vi` or some other editor on the resulting file-with-conflicts.

Git includes the `git merge-file` command, which does the three-way merge on any three input files (and in fact you can use `git merge-file` directly from Mercurial).  Note that both `git merge-file` and `diff3` already exit 0 if they are able to merge files successfully, and nonzero if not.

---

<sup>1</sup>Mercurial allows the selection of different merge algorithms here, and there have been multiple offerings: see [Consensus Merge](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/ConsensusMerge) and [Bid Merge](https://www.mercurial-scm.org/wiki/BidMerge).  Git, too, allows different merge algorithms, which it calls *strategies*, and its default is what it calls the *recursive* strategy.  It's up to this high level stage of merging to select files to pair up for the low level merging process, or—in the case of Git's recursive merge—*construct* files, in some cases.

<sup>2</sup>The source code suggests that Mercurial could defer this to later, saving the high level conflicts in the merge state.  I did not keep poking at it but was not able to find a way to do that, though.